# Shrink image using python?

Tags: python

```
import image

img = image.Image("test_image.png")
ratio = 0.5

#Make new image screen.
new_width = img.getWidth()*(ratio)
new_height = img.getHeight()*(ratio)

new_img = image.EmptyImage(new_width,new_height)
win = image.ImageWin(new_width,new_height)


for col in range(img.getHeight()):
    for row in range(img.getWidth()):
        p = img.getPixel(row*ratio, col*ratio) #Color value stays the same.
        new_img.setPixel(row*ratio,col*ratio,p)
                

new_img.draw(win)
win.exitonclick()
```

This is my attempt to shrink an image using Python. I know my algorithm is clearly not correct but I can't seem to wrap my head around what I should do instead.

It's giving me an image of the two upper corners of the original image put side by side in my new smaller image screen. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you multiply by `ratio` in `p = img.getPixel(row*ratio, col*ratio)`?

Comment: Well, you're using exactly the same coordinates for the pixels you're getting from the original image, and the pixels you're setting in the new image - how is that supposed to scale anything?

Comment: Right, I know I'm not scaling correctly. How should I instead?

Comment: By getting the value of the correct pixel by not multiplying by `ratio` in `p = img.getPixel(row*ratio, col*ratio)` :-/

Comment: How can I get the correct value of the pixel?

Comment: **by not multiplying by `ratio`**

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't work. It prints a distorted-color image of the two left halves of the image.